Towing a VW Trans T30 180TDI 4 wheel drive. Registration year 2012
Will towing this vehicle with all four wheel on the road at speeds in excess of 50 mph cause major damage to the automatic transmission.  I believe the box is a DSG.
I have been trying to obtain the drivers handbook from VW which gives this information but at the moment there are none available......help please!

You show it to be a "Trans T30" ... is this a Transporter T30?

DSG gearboxes aren't made to be towed. It will damage the gearbox, especially at high speeds or for long periods without any lubrication. I suggest using a flatbed and lifting all four wheels off the ground.

Try these links;
https://www.vw.com/en/owners-and-services/about-my-vehicle/owners-manual.html
https://www.manualslib.com/manual/748761/Volkswagen-Transporter.html
https://www.vwserviceandparts.com/digital-resources/online-owners-manual/
